# Add Row based on cell value, Below the last data in column A

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I just need some help, I got this code in youtube that adds rows to the specified sheet, but the code that I got is just adding rows after row 2 and just keeps on adding it non-stop.

here is the code:

```js
function insertRow() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheetToAdd = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('test sheet');

  let lastRowEdit = sheetToAdd.getLastRow();

  for(var i = 2; i <= lastRowEdit; i++)
  {
    sheetToAdd.insertRowAfter(i);
  }
}
```

What I want is to add row below the last row with data in column A. And the number of the rows to be added is based on cell B2 in another sheet

sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sX6wS0ZPeLC1u0nbU2m8jeZ3dMVEXhkFPR_Ply27Z18/edit#gid=746083055

Comment: Hey, please provide a bit more info especially that you have an empty google-sheet 'test sheet' and how to accomplish the state to test your code. Maybe you could provide a link to a shared document as minimal (non-)working example.

Comment: Furhtermore it is super unclear what you want to accomplish and therefore it is not possible to help you. Yes the code does what you describe not more not less. To set a value you could use 'sheetToAdd.getActiveCell().setValue('some value');'

Comment: Hello! sorry if I wasn't clear with what I am asking, what I want is to add a row below the last cell with data in column A. The number of rows to add depends on the cell value on cell B2 in other sheet, here's the sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sX6wS0ZPeLC1u0nbU2m8jeZ3dMVEXhkFPR_Ply27Z18/edit#gid=746083055

Comment: Please clearify that in your question. Thats much clearer.

Comment: already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may solve your issue:
Prerequisite: A google spreadsheet with one sheet called Info containing the amount of rows to add in cell 'B2'.
A sheet called 'add here' which will be filled by the script below.

By changing it according to your sheet names you can basically copy pasta it.

Comments for help!

```js
function insertRow() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // activates the opened document
  let sheetToAdd = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('add here'); // selects the sheet at the bottom of the SpreadSheet (SpreadSheet is a collection of Sheets (!))

  let rowsToAdd = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Info').getRange(2,2).getValue(); // get cell B2

  let lastRow = sheetToAdd.getLastRow() + 1; // you want to add after the last row with data
  
  for(var i = 0; i <= rowsToAdd; i++){
    sheetToAdd.getRange(lastRow+i, 1).setValue(i); // get the cell at lastRow+counter and column 1; set the value as wished
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! sorry for the late response, I tried your code and it works. But there is a problem that I encountered, it adds 1 additional blank row, so if in cell B2 the value is 2, the rows to add after execution of code will be 3, this is not a problem at first but I have observed that if there's a blank row at the bottom, and tries to execute the code again, it won't add any rows. so there should be no blank rows below.

Comment: tried changing things up, but I can't figure it out, either it adds 1 additional row on top of the value in B2 or it just adds 1 row.

Comment: Change the <= to < this is the reason why it iterates one more than intended.